# Variable referenced before assignment (but the variable is within the function, after assignment)

Tags: python

Here is the python code:

```
else:
    z = test
    x = world
    y = x + z

cur.execute("""SELECT this FROM that WHERE they = %s""", (y, ))
```

But I'm getting the error that the variable y is being referenced before assignment, yet clearly it is within the function...

Comment: More information needed.  Probably the `if` block was entered and y was never assigned.

Comment: i've triple checked and this is not the case

Comment: Well then you have to provide more code.  How is anyone supposed to help you when it is impossible to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the `if` part is *not* assigning any value to `y` (we can't tell because it's not shown in the question). To be sure, add this at the beginning, before the `if` statement (that is, assuming that the `else` corresponds to an `if`):

```
y = "" # initialize with a value appropriate to the problem
```

Comment: i've checked and this is not the case unfortunately